# What is the symbol for the exponentiation operation in ATS?

Tags: ats

For instance, how can I write an expression in ATS for the 10th power of x? I tried both x^10 and x^^10, but neither worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exponentiation operator both for integer and float values in ATS is `**`, as in `implement main0 () = println! (2 ** 10) // prints 1024`.